# Why in Shiva Mahapuran the rajasik and the Tamasik and Satwik deities are different. Pls answer according to Vaishnava perspective

Tags: puranas, vedanta, upanishads, dvaita

Vishnu, Rudra and I (Brahma) represent the Gunas.

Siva is free from Gunas. He is the Supreme Brahman, the undecaying.

Vishnu is of Sattva attribute, I (Brahma) am of Rajas attribute and Rudra is of Tamas attribute. This is only in the view of activities in this world. But in fact in name it is otherwise.

Vishnu is Taamasik nature within

Goddess of speech is Rajasic nature; Sati is of Saattvika nature and Lakshmi is of Taamasika nature; the great Goddess Sivaa is of three natures.

As I knew earlier and as mentioned in many scriptures the opposite is correct. Then why is it mentioned like this and why do many Vaishnav scriptures glorify Lord Shiva as supreme more than Shaiva scripturesglorifying Lord Sri Hari as supreme. Vaishnav perspective answer pls

Comment: Please remove the Advaita tag. The question is puranic.